# The Most Useless Program EVER!

Tags: code-golf

Inspired by [The Most Useless Machine Ever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z86V_ICUCD4).

Write the shortest program that does the following:

- create a graphical window, then immediately close the window and exit the program.
- do this in some visually apparent manner. Like the "arm" that pushes the switch in the machine, the program must use some visual method in the GUI to close itself.
- this visual method must be what causes the program to close; you cannot just show it as something on the side (though there may be other things off to the side)

Note:

- The program does not have to be visible long enough for the visible activity to be seen by a human as long as the activity is the cause of the closing.
- The window must be a GUI (must display a graphical window that contains the visible exit method).
- The visual method needs to be something the user could do if it wasn't done automatically. Explain what needs to be changed in the code for the user to be able to do this (Thanks to Iszi).
- The program must close if there is no interference from the user, but if the user interferes, then it does not need to close automatically.
- Please include an explanation of what it is that causes the program to close.

Example: a window containing a button which is programmatically clicked, running a short snippet of code that closes the program.

Comment: I'd suggest that, for programs not visible enough to be seen by a human, answers should include mention of what should be changed in the code (adding/increasing timer values, etc. - but not fundamentally changing its functionality) in order to demonstrate to a human that it actually does something visual.

Comment: Should this be code golf or a popularity contest?

Comment: I've changed my TI-BASIC answer to a compiled version that is shorter than my other answer (which is currently accepted). I'd appreciate it if you could change that :)

Comment: I'm curious why this question is being DVd and VTCd. For one, this has an objective winning criterion; it's a [code-golf]. I can understand that this isn't the best question, but why is it being VTCd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TI-Basic, 3 bytes

```
DispGraph:1

hex: 31 3E DF
```

**Explanation**

`DispGraph` Displays the graph (a graphical window)

`:1` Simulates a press of `1` (by storing `1` to `Ans` at the last step of a program), which takes the calculator back to the home screen. A user could do the same thing.

Comment: GTB is kind of stupid considering that the symbols for each command are stored a 2-byte values.

Comment: Concurred, I (from inspection using CalcSys) would count as 6(perhaps 4, not sure if all OSs use single-byte tokens for `:` and `1`). Filesystem overhead and tables are obviously not included in the count.

Comment: What do you mean by compiled? TI-BASIC is interpreted.

Comment: @Jakob Back then I was more confused about how TI-Basic worked. What I should have said is the source is 3 1-byte tokens. Let me fix this answer

Comment: @Jakob There we go. I think back then we were scoring TI-Basic programs by ascii byte count rather than tokens

Comment: Oh yeah, I wondered if the age of the answer had something to do with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby with [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com), 110

```
Shoes.app{button('Close'){exit}
p=para
t=Time.now
animate{u=(t-Time.now).to_i+10
exit if u<0
p.text=' '*u+?<}}
```

Makes a little arrow that pushes a "Close" button. (Pushing the close button manually also closes the window.)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

### Windows Batch, 4 bytes

Save the following program to a `.bat` file in your user folder (C:\Users\username):

```
Exit
```

When executed from the **Start, Run** prompt, a new window opens, types the command `Exit` and executes it.

Comment: *"The window must be a GUI (must display a graphical window that contains the visible exit method)."* - it's arguable if your window contains the visible exit method, I'd say it doesn't.

Comment: @gronostaj It has an X in the top-right corner.

Comment: Ah, I see - you're exploiting the rules. There is a visible method to exit and user can do the same thing program does, but those are two different methods to terminate it. That's clever, +1.

Comment: Creating a .bat with only a space character: 1 byte?

Comment: @SEarle1986, the space character wouldn't cause the program to exit.  It would exit because it reached the end of the batch file.  `Exit` will cause the window to close before the batch file completes.

Answer (score 4):

#### JavaScript: <del>133</del> 117

(You need to allow popups in your web browser for this to work)

Code-golfed:

```
(function(){w=window.open(),d=999,i=setInterval(function(){w.resizeTo(d-=9,d),d<0&&(clearInterval(i),w.close())})})()
```

Source:
http://jsfiddle.net/gt2t8/2/

Comment: Why does it resize?

Comment: @Quincunx `do this in some visually apparent manner. Like the "arm" that pushes the switch in the machine, the program must use some visual method in the GUI to close itself.`

Comment: reduced to 117 chars: `(function(){w=window.open(),d=999,i=setInterval(function(){w.resizeTo(d-=9,d);if(d<0)clearInterval(i),w.close()})})()`

Comment: @Griffin thanks! Updated with your suggestions

Comment: One that I can run without leaving the page. Awesome.

Comment: Always think JS answers should get -75, so I don't have to leave... and then +50 for having to disable popups

Answer (score 4):

### [Golf-Basic 84](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1261), <s>5</s> 4

```
g`:1
```

Display the graph, simluate a press of 1, closing the graph and returning home.

Comment: Does this do the same as your other answer?

Comment: @Quincunx Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2):

### x86 / Win32 assembly (<del>337</del> <del>310</del> 271 bytes)

```
.586
.model flat
option casemap:none
include kernel32.inc
include windows.inc
include user32.inc
i textequ <invoke>
.code
s:i CreateThread,0,0,$+46,0,0,0
i MessageBox,0,$,$,0
i ExitProcess,0
i Sleep,999
i FindWindow,0,$
i PostMessage,eax,256,13,0
ret
END s
```

Assembles with MASM32 (`ml /c /coff /Gz /I<include path> test.asm` / `link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /LIBPATH:<library path> test.obj kernel32.lib user32.lib`).

It creates a MessageBox with an *"OK"* button, and a thread that simulates a carriage return press from the user after 999 ms.

The `$` is substituted with the address of the beginning of the `code` section by the assembler/linker. The first instruction is a `push byte 0` (implicitly, since it's generated by the `invoke`), which is encoded as `6A 00`, which equals the null-terminated string `"j"`. I take advantage of this when calling `MessageBox` and `FindWindow`.

Comment: Is the assembly 271 bytes, or is that the size of the machine code?

Answer (score 1):

## Bash with X Window System, 10 chars

```
xterm -e :
```

Open an xterm window, run the bash no-op `:`, after which the xterm window closes.

If you want to see the useless window for a second, you can change the `:` to `sleep 1`:

```
xterm -e sleep 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl/Tk, 131

```
grid [button .b -command exit]
event generate .b <Button-1> -warp 1 -x 5 -y 5
event generate .b <ButtonRelease-1> -warp 1 -x 5 -y 5
```

## Tcl/Tk, 136

```
grid [button .b -command exit]
event generate .b <ButtonPress-1> -warp 1 -x 5 -y 5
event generate .b <ButtonRelease-1> -warp 1 -x 5 -y 5
```

It needs to be ran on an interactive shell, line by line and user can not move the mouse between.

1. Application starts

[image]

2. Button whose behaviour is to close the app is added to the app window

[image]

3. Generate an event that presses down the mouse on the button — Altough the cursor is not visible in the screenshot it is over the button; it is visible the buttonhas been pressed because it now sunken in, and before it was embossed out.

[image]

4. Finally generate an event that releases the mouse button up.

   a. Image before really sending it (before pressing Enter)
   [image]

   b. After Enter the interactive shell and the app windows just disappeared.
   [image]

**Note to tcl'ers:**
Tried to do the same directly on the window's X Close button using:

```
event generate . <ButtonPress-1> -warp 1 -x 175 -y -10
event generate . <ButtonRelease-1> -warp 1 -x 175 -y -10
```

but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash - echo  (50 bytes)

**Not golfed, 54 bytes:**

```
s=sleep;echo -n \>\\;$s 1;echo -ne "\b\b >/";$s 1;echo
```

**Golfed, 50 bytes**

I can't exactly display the golf version here because the backspace characters actually backspace.  For the golf version, change both of the "^H" to single backspace (^H) characters:

```
s=sleep;echo -n \>\\;$s 1;echo -n ^H^H \>/;$s 1;echo
```

**Notes:**

- The activity is visible for 2 seconds.
- It doesn't use a window manager or anything of that sort, but I count the ASCII art as a "gui".  If you are running the command in a terminal window, which is now the usual case, the activity is displayed in that window.  It does not open up a new window.
- The user can close the program sooner than the automatic close by hitting "CTRL-C" within 2 seconds of starting the program.  Users who are more comfortable using their GUI can put their cursor on the little "X" in the corner of the terminal window, quickly, and "click" it.
- The program closes after 2 seconds if there is no interference from the user.  The user can only cause it to close sooner.
- What causes the program to close is the completion of the final "echo".